# C# Rx Observable.Never<> behaves like Observable.Empty<>?

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, subscribe

I'm new to Rx and have this code snippet for a try.

```
Observable.Never<string>().Subscribe(Console.Write);
Observable.Empty<string>().Subscribe(Console.Write);
```

I expected that `Never<string>()` will behave like `Console.ReadKey` which will not end, but as I run these 2 lines, they end immediately, so [Never] behaves like [Empty] to me.

What is the correct understanding of [Never] and is there a good sample usage for it?

Comment: all subscriptions "code line" end immediately, you are just providing a callback that is called on each "OnNext" as argument to the `Subscribe`. Neither `Never` or `Empty` emit any `OnNext`. However, `Empty` emits `OnCompleted` immediately. (for which you don't provide any callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't have a ton of experience with Rx, but I believe all `Subscribe` is doing is registering what to do when the observable emits. If your observable never emits (ie `Empty` or `Never`) then the method is never called. The application is not waiting for the subscription itself to end. If you wanted to wait forever you would use something like

```
Observable.Never<string>().Wait();
```

This ties back into the reason you should not use async operation in `Subscribe`. Take the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Observable.Range(1, 5).Subscribe(async x => await DoTheThing(x));
  Console.WriteLine("done");
}

static async Task DoTheThing(int x)
{
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x));
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

When run the application will immediately write "done" and exit after pushing the values into the observable because it is unaware of the subscriber in the context of whether it has completed its handling or not. Hopefully I made that clear, and if someone with more Rx knowledge wants to step in to help if needed that'd be good.

Answer (score 3):

Both the `Observable.Never()` and `Observable.Empty()` observable will not emit any values. However, the observable built with `Observable.Never()` will not complete and instead stays "open/active". It might be a difference at the location where you consume these observable if the observable completes (`Empty()`) or not (`Never()`), but this depends on your actual use-case.

Having observables which doesn't emit any values might sound useless, but maybe you are at a location where you *have to* provide an observable (instead of using `null`). So you can write something like this:

```
public override IObservable<string> NameChanged => Observable.Never<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This link gives you the difference between **empty**,**never** ,and **throw**:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html
And this is one usage of **Never**:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/NEVER